# Every compact in a locally compact Hausdorff space is covered by a relatively compact open subset

Tags: general-topology

I know that if $X$ is a locally compact (non-compact) Hausdorff space and $K \subset X$ is compact, then there exists a relatively compact open set $G$ such that $K \subset G$. Now, in this context $\bar{G}$ is a normal space, so we can apply Urysohn's lemma to the sets $K$ and $\bar{G} \setminus G$.

I need to do this in some proof but, in order to apply Urysonh's lemma I need the set $\bar{G} \setminus G$ to be non-empty. So, my question is:

If $X$ is a locally compact (non-compact) Hausdorff space and $K \subset X$ is compact, can we always find a relatively compact open set $G$ such that $K \subset G$ and $G$ is not closed?

Thanks in advance for all the replies.

Comment: Why do you need $G$ which is not closed? This is a very artificial assumption.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider any infinite discrete space.